# Is Ubuntu 12.04 Grub version compatible with Windows 8?

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2

I want to install Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I want to know if I won't have any trouble with windows 8 on GRUB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes It works seamlessly.

The only problem I faced was that grub continued to display the OS name as Windows 7 in grub loader menu.

If you wish you may fix that using these commands:

1. `cd /etc/grub.d/`
2. `sudo gedit 30_os-proper`
3. search for:

```
    case ${LONGNAME} in
        Windows\ Vista*|Windows\ 7*|Windows\ Server\ 2008*)
        ;;
        *)
```

1. change the Value of 7 to 8 or
2. insert text '|Windows\ 7*|Windows\ 8*|'
3. run `sudo update-grub`
4. Reboot your PC to verify :)

Answer (score 0):

No trouble at all. I have both of them installed in dual boot using grub